# object traking within a video file

Tags: c#, image, opencv, video-processing

I have an intresting project assigned to me , and I would like if you can provide me with an idea of what I should look for and read and learn.

(Im not asking for solutions )

I have to make a windows application using C# that have an option to load a video file (avi or any) and then the application detect a specific color or an object such as a ball or a face or whatever.

I heard there is a library called opencv and Im learning a lot from it .

I would like to learn more and more , but I want to avoid wasting my time on somthing old or not applicable.

please advice

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Googling first? The 3rd result from searching *opencv track* is this fantastic post:

[Tracking colored objects in OpenCV](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/)

> If you’re new to image processing, you’ll enjoy this project. What we’ll attempt to achieve in this tutorial is tracking the location of a coloured object in an image. In our case, it’ll be a yellow colored ball.

Comment: I Select your answer as the best between the hundreds recived :-)