# OpenCV finding picture (frame) in video

Tags: c++, c, opencv, video, image-processing

I am trying to create small application in C++ that will return probability value (real number from 0 to 1) for recognizing two pictures in video. My idea is to find commercials in certain video material. I was thinking to cut first frame from commercial as well as the last one. In that way I could create app, using OpenCV, that will load a video (TV content) and then it will search for the first frame catted from commercials. If it finds it (with probability more than SOME_PARAMETER) than app can conclude that that commercials starts there. Then I would like to search for the last frame and if it's found (again with probability more than SOME_PARAMETER) than the app can conclude that wanted commercial really exists in given video. This is just an idea. I am expert in C++ but totally newbie with OpenCV. If someone can point me out, or give an example it would be much appreciated. Of course I am open to any suggestions regarding idea. Thanks,

M.

Comment: how did you want to find the commercial? scanning images for similarity?

Comment: As for how you could get frame from a video, page 356 of docs.opencv.org/opencv_tutorials.pdf has a simple example of getting each frame and showing it. As for how to detect commercials, you need to search papers.

Comment: @Jonathan D: Scanning images for similarity was my idea.

Comment: @MilošLjumović, you finally find first and last frame of ads ?

Comment: I have at that time. Though I haven't opened that project for a long time. Do you need advice or smth?

Comment: yes , i am work on same functionality, can you share your advice ?

Answer (score 14):

What you are looking for is known as **template matching** in OpenCV.

To get acquainted with OpenCV you should start reading [some tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680049/176769), besides the books there are some good ones on the web. As a C++ guy, you will probably **use the C++ interface** of OpenCV which uses `cv::Mat` as the main data structure to represent images. If you see the `IplImage` data type being used, know it's from the C interface.

After the preliminaries, you will eventually need to learn how to read frames from a video:

- [Reading a video with openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14838999/176769)
- [Read/write avi video using openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777135/176769)

and then how to process those frames, individually:

- [OpenCV every frame processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3919216/176769) (C interface)
- [How to find object on video using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788739/176769)
- [Object traking within a video file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9929714/176769)
- [Very Slow Processing of my Opencv Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13235942/176769)

Finally, you will investigate how [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) works:

- [How can I perform Template Matching process in SUB-IMAGE extracted from ORIGINAL-IMAGE and Display the results in Original Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15606231/176769)
- [How to handle template matching with multiple occurences](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/how-to-handle-template-matching-with-multiple-occurences/)

There are other ways to track objects besides template matching, check these references:

- [Comparison of OpenCV's feature detection algorithms](https://computer-vision-talks.com/2011-07-13-comparison-of-the-opencv-feature-detection-algorithms/)
- [Object Tracking using OpenCV (C++/Python)](https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

Comment: Thanks @karlphillip I will try to work something out. Thanks.

Comment: @karlphilip last two link's are broken.

Comment: @MageshPandian Thank you. Unfortunately, the last link could not be found anywhere else so I replaced it with more updated stuff.